# how to convert a string with comma separated values within a list in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list

Hi I'm relatively new to python and not quite getting a resolve for the mentioned issue

I have an input list `['abc','def','asd,trp','faq']`

Expected Output list `['abc','def','asd','trp','faq']`

please help in achieving the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the list and check if a comma exists and if it does, split and extend, if not, append to an output list.

```
lst = ['abc','def','asd,trp','faq']
out = []
for item in lst:
    if ',' in item:
        out.extend(item.split(','))
    else:
        out.append(item)
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'def', 'asd', 'trp', 'faq']
```

Since you tagged pandas, using pandas, you can also do:

```
out = pd.Series(lst).str.split(',').explode().tolist()
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `split` in list comprehension:

```
L = ['abc','def','asd,trp','faq']

L1 = [y for x in L for y in x.split(',')]
print (L1)
['abc', 'def', 'asd', 'trp', 'faq']
```